# How to make a div change its height automatically when the height of its content changes?

Tags: css, html

I am creating a division, in which there are some elements. For the example below, there is a sentence inside a division. However when the sentence becomes very long when I insert something through ajax, it seems like the height of the division does not change.

```
<div style="width:300px;min-height:10px;background:red">
<div style="width:100px;height:inherit;background:blue;float:left"></div>
<a style="width:100px;height:10px;float:left">The length of this sentence is always changing.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/uCa64/

Comment: jQuery is well too http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/uCa64/1/

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong example, I have just updated it

Comment: hi im not sure you are looking for! is this what you mean.[click me](http://jsfiddle.net/uCa64/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the height for the div using javascript or using jquery

assign a ID to div e.g

```
 <div style="width:300px;min-height:10px;background:red" id="test"> 
   <a>The length of this sentence is always changing.</a>
 </div>

 $.ajax({
    $(function() {
      $("#test").width(100).height(200);//set height or width here
   });
 });
```

try to set the height here...